# MS Fakes on VSO Build

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, microsoft-fakes

I have a set of unit tests that use Shims from MS Fakes to test some static methods. I am currently using 4 fake assemblies, all of which reside in a single assembly. This fakes assembly is then referenced by the unit test assemblies that need it.

When we run locally in VS2013, all is fine, but when we try to do a build in Visual Studio Online, it fails with the following type of error:

```
MockLogManager.cs (25): 'ShimJsonLogger' does not contain a definition for 'LogGet'
```

Any ideas why it seems to be building the ShimJsonLogger but not giving it all of the properties we need?

Comment: May be the generated *.fakes.dll in VSO have a problem. Does the build logs show any warnings related to fakes generation? Turning on diagnostic flags in *.fakes may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mpeder/archive/2014/02/10/debugging-and-diagnosing-ms-fakes.aspx

Comment: @ArunM, thanks we did that and it has given us more information but it looks like a current limitation in VS2015.